# flashbuilder actionscript project from windows to mac

Tags: windows, apache-flex, actionscript-3, macos

I created an ActionScript project with Flash Builder 4 in windows. now I try to open the project from OSX (with flash builder burrito)

but I get a

```
configuration variable 'compiler.library-path' value contains unknown token 'FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG' myProj Unknown Flex Problem
```

I can't find 'FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG' in my Flex Compiler additional arguments. what could this mean?

Answer (score 3):

Check your project properties.

Check the build paths first.

The "FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG" reference should be there pointing to a location within the installation trying to reference a resource of some type.

The "FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG" is a file system path variable which is replaced by another value.
It is the same a "key-value-pair".

Either remove the variable (if you are not using it), or add the environment variable.
You should find the environment variable within the Adobe Flash publishing settings.
There should also be another reference to this variable store in a configuration file.

Comment: Just for reference and b/c it's somewhat buried in the prefs :) you can edit the environment variables by going here: Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Linked Resources

Answer (score 1):

as sunil mentioned:
check your flash builder : Window > preferences > workspace->linked resources there you should see one called FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG , mine points to adobe flash cs5 > Common > Configuration